# Are Android Preferences fully supported on AndroidTV?

Tags: android-preferences, android-tv

I am loading a preferencescreen in an activity so that a user can enter an ip address to connect to.  This is so they can connect to their running MythTV Backend.

My preference screen renders correctly.  I can navigate up and down the list and jump into sub categories.

There is an EditTextPrefrerence box for the mythtv backend ip address.  The edit text shows as a popup dialog with the on screen keyboard below it.  It is only a single field, but the keyboard shows a Next button instead of a Done button on the side.  When complete, you have to click the back button on the remote to send focus back to the the edit text dialog.  From here you can either select Cancel or OK.

Should preferences such as this be handled differently?

Comment: Should preferences be handled by a GuidedStepFragment? [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/GuidedStepFragment.html)

Comment: Take a look to `LeanbackSettingsFragment`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/preference/LeanbackSettingsFragment.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, preferences are handled on Android TV in the same way that you are used to on Android.

Regarding the use of `GuidedStepFragment`, it does not handle you preferences automatically, but it is the most typical way of presenting a settings screen to the user.

I would encourage you using `GuidedStepFragment` in order to save your preferences then.

Comment: Thanks @dextor Regarding this issue with the onscreen keyboard. Have you seen this issue?

Comment: I haven't experienced it directly, might be a bug though. Since the code can run both on Android and on Android TV, can you compare the two behaviors?

Comment: On the phone its no issue at all. Only on Android TV, so I am inclined to agree that it is a bug. If I get some time I will try to dig a little deeper. However, I am looking forward to see if the guidedstepfragment makes for a better experience.